# Rails 3 and partial usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Assume, I know what the partial's name is and where it is located. Could I know where it might be used? E.g. in what controller and action it is rendered or what view it is included in?

Comment: You could `grep` for the partial's name in your `app/` directory.

Comment: I mean, how I can do it from within rails application

Answer (score 1):

params[:controller] and params[:action] will tell you the controller and action from within the partial.

Comment: That won't do. I'm not in the controller. I need to get this as separate service: I will just have a name of file, that's all and I'll need to get the places where it is used through the project

Comment: Not 100% sure what you need, but params work in views/partials too. <% params[:controller] %> in a view will tell you the controller that triggered the view/partial.

Is this a code need? If so, could you provide some pseudocode? Your comment makes it sound as if you simply need to do a search through the entire project for mentions of the file...

Comment: find controllers which may use a partial "_my_items" #=> [{:controller => 'first', :action => 'index', :method => 'post'}, {:controller => 'second', :action => 'show', :method => 'get'}]

Comment: Hmm...pretty sure there's no way to do what you need. Sorry.